# Listview error,android stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

This is the code am working,Android is stopped,but am getting correct json,may be problem with list view,whether i have to use listview id some where..
my listview id is 'list'..

```
*public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_jobs);
        kywrd = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Keyword");
        loc = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Location");
        farea = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Funcarea");
        exp = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Experience");
        indus = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Industry");
        jobList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        new postdetails().execute();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txttitle)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ViewJob.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra (TAG_JOBTITLE,pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }





    class postdetails extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String validUser = "false";
        protected void OnPreExecute()   {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog=new ProgressDialog(SearchResult.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... args)
        {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Job_Keyword",kywrd));  
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("All_Location",loc));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Job_Func_Area",farea));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Job_Max_Exp",exp));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Job_Industry","indus"));
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST",params);
            Log.d("user : ", json.toString());
            try {  
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1)
                {
                    user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_JOB);
                        validUser = "true";
                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String title = c.getString(TAG_JOBTITLE);
                            String loca = c.getString(TAG_JOBLOC);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();                            map.put(TAG_JOBTITLE,title);
                            map.put(TAG_JOBLOC,loca);
                            jobList.add(map);
                        }
                }
                else
                    validUser = "false";
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return validUser;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String validUser) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(validUser=="true")
                {      
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    SearchResult.this,jobList,
                                    R.layout.job_list, new String[] {TAG_JOBTITLE,
                                            TAG_JOBTITLE},
                                    new int[] { R.id.txttitle,R.id.txtloc});
                                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
                        params.clear();
        }
        }
}***
```

Comment: what is the eroor log is showing?

Comment: post the logcat error....

Comment: From the above code we are not clear whether you extended class is Activity or ListActivity,

If you used ListActivity and using xml layout file for the UI then you must declare listview with "@android:id/list".

If you used Activity, there is not restriction on assigning listview id.

If the above solution won't work, please post the logcat message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set your id in listview as `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

to

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

where the id of the listview is "android:id/list"

Comment: nice to hear that.. happy coding!